# Apollo Angular Add-- Couldn't read tsconfig.base.json

Tags: angular, apollo

English is not my native language, please excuse typing errors.
I was read anther solution, modify the version, but its execution result is still error.
I don’t know if the version update will affect each other.

I run this code
`ng add apollo-angular`

The execution results are as follows：

```
> ng add apollo-angular
Skipping installation: Package already installed
? Url to your GraphQL endpoint
Couldn't read tsconfig.base.json!
```

My `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.4",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.4",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.12",
    "apollo-angular": "^2.0.4",
    "apollo-angular-link-http": "^1.11.0",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "graphql-modules": "^1.4.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jw-paginate": "^1.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^10.2.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
```

`tsconfig.json`have this array

```
"lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ]
```

Have other had similar problems? How did you manage to finally resolve the situation in the end?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there were a series of issues that this "solution style tsconfig" approach introduced, so they've decided to (at least temporarily) roll it back.

Refer : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eB6cGCG_2ircfS5GzpDC9dBgikeYYcMxghVH5sDESHw/edit

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but I can't downgrade to Angular9, maybe the original version is Anuglar10?
At first i didn't have `tsconfig,base,json`